# Disable drag-and-drop in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Many text editors have a feature which allows you to click-and-drag some text from one part of the file and drop it somewhere else. Can this be disabled in Notepad++ v6.3 (UNICODE)? I carefully searched Settings > Preferences but found no option for this.

Comment: >Can this be disabled in Notepad++ -> IMHO it is NOT possible!

Comment: If correct that is a shame. Might try to add a feature request...

Comment: You can try to add it to the list: https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues

Comment: Good suggestion, have added issue #2571

Comment: Please answer your own question, so we do not get bothered whit this (never solved) problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of August 2023, this is still unresolved in Notepad++.

Issue was raised [against the Notepad++ GitHub project](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/2571) and closed by one of the project maintainers with the `wontfix` tag. The reason given is that the problem is with the Scintilla editor that NPP relies on. [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700696/disabling-drag-and-drop-of-text-in-notepad) investigates the issue with the suggestion to rebuild Notepad++ from source.

Issue has also been raised [against the Scintilla SourceForge project](https://sourceforge.net/p/scintilla/feature-requests/184/). There has been limited activity on this issue and it remains unresolved (i.e. still a problem in the latest versions of NPP).

Conclusion: Except by resorting to building yourself a local, custom version of NPP this is not possible.